# Why isn't the view updating?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a login page in my application and on the page i have a textbox that shows the error in case of wrong username/password, etc. I am updating the error from view model, but the view is not changing automatically.

The viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Error definition.

```
string _error;

    public string Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
        set 
        {
            _error = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Error");
        }
    }
```

INotify Event Handlers

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
```

update

```
_error = "Wrong username/password!";
```

xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Error, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What else am i missing?

Comment: did you set datacontext?  and show your XAML binding

Comment: You should be setting Error not _error

Comment: I have set the datacontext. Other fields like username work and command like login are binded perfectly in view.

Comment: Thanks! used Error instead of _error and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your error like this, you're just changing the private member that isn't being binded to:

```
Error="Wrong username/password!";
```

not `_error`